# MySQL slave replication permission error

Tags: mysql, replication

I am having a rather frustrating issue. I have granted replication client to a user on the slave instance of MySQL. I can login using the username and password. I can exectute "SHOW SLAVE STATUS;" but I cannot start or stop the slave thread. I get the error below when i issue "STOP SLAVE" or "START SLAVE".

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: the error meaning when trying to connect to MySQL you entered the wrong password or no password at all

Comment: @ahmad, I am already connected and in the MySQL commandline.

Comment: when the slave SID to to replicate Master SID it required user name and password MASTER_USER and MASTER_PASSWORD to log in and replicate, if the master password is blank or wrong you will get the same error message

Comment: @ahmad, replication on the server is working fine. I just need the user to be able to start and stop the slave thread.

Comment: you may need to grant super privileges to the user. Replication client is responsible only to replicate binary logs to slave.

Comment: From the manual: STOP SLAVE requires the REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN (8.0) or SUPER privilege (5.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to grant super privileges to the user. Replication client is responsible only to replicate binary logs to slave

Comment: WARNING: Your answer is correct (+1). However, you do not want to give away SUPER privilege to just anybody. You should leave that to root@localhost or a designated super user of MySQL.